# HTTP Log with Datetime in .net 7 web API

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api, .net-7.0

I have a .net 7 web API project. I want to set the logs, in order that it logs every http call that has been made. In this logs I also want to see the datetime of the call.

So far my settings are this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields =
        //HttpLoggingFields.RequestHeaders | 
        HttpLoggingFields.RequestMethod |
        HttpLoggingFields.RequestPath |
        HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody |
        HttpLoggingFields.ResponseBody |
        HttpLoggingFields.ResponseStatusCode;
    logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 512;
    logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 512;
});
```

I'm not finding any document that explains how to add the datetime

Comment: But datetime is already part of all log messages. It should be included in the log message you see logged.

Comment: @ThomasArdal I thought so, but it doesn't appear. The code that I show is the only code I wrote for logs, apart from `app.UseHttpLogging();`

Comment: Where do you store your logs? Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
It can be set either in the program.cs or in the appsettings.json file.

Here is how I set the appsettings.json file:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        },
        "FormatterName": "simple",
        "FormatterOptions": {
            "SingleLine": true,
            "IncludeScopes": false,
            "TimestampFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss UTC ",
            "UseUtcTimestamp": true
        }
    }
}
```

The important part is the "FormatterName" set as simple, json or systemd (based on your preference), then inside the "FormatterOptions" you can set the format of timestamp.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter) for full documentation.